# Error when applying .map_partition on a column over a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I recently decided to be more adventurous and try to explore more DASK dataframes. I am trying to apply a specific function to one of the column dataframe, the syntax that I am using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': [300,300,450,500,500,750,600,300, 150],'Column 2': [100,130,230,200,300,350,600,550,530], 'Column 3': [250, 300, 400, 500, 700,350, 750, 550, 600]})

def TestFunc(x):
    y = x*2 + abs(x/2 - x*3)
    return y

dd_data = dd.from_pandas(df_data, npartitions = 1)
data_test = dd.map_partitions(TestFunc,dd_data['Column 1'])
data_test.compute()
```

Naturally is a simpler example that I just made up to show how what I have been doing. This code is working well, the problem is on the real situation that I am facing. Now, I have a more complex dataframe where I want to apply a function to one column. I am applying the following function:

```
 def GetID(phase):
     nDataPoints = len(phase)
     myRanges = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0,360,6))
     phase[phase>np.deg2rad(354+3)] = 0
     ID = np.array([])
     for i in np.arange(0,nDataPoints):
         val = abs(myRanges-phase[i])
         iID = np.argmin(val)
         ID = np.append(ID, iID+1)
     return ID
```

I am able to apply the function to the column with `.map_partitions`, the problem is that when I try to use after  `.compute()` to see the numerical results I receive an error `Key error: 0`. I don't understand how I would have no problem with my previous simpler example and with the situation that I am facing.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one! Suggestions of what to look up for are also welcome

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying your function on a normal Pandas dataframe to verify that it is working correctly:

```
GetID(df.compute())
```

If that works then I would next try using the single threaded scheduler, along with the `pdb` module to investigate the traceback

```
df.map_partitions(GetID).compute(scheduler='single-threaded')
```

This is easy to do if you are in IPython with the `%debug` magic.